# Display the HTML panel next to infowindow on Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing the Google Map web application using Google Map 3 library, I want to add the HTML panel when I click on button on infowindow. The panel position always beside the infowindow. Can everyone help me or give me an example to resolve it?

It looks like this:
[image]

For example I have some code, could I display the div #panel on the right of the div #content?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Info windows</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
// This example displays a marker at the center of Australia.
// When the user clicks the marker, an info window opens.

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="btn_know_more"> Know more'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div id="panel">
      <!--Content panel-->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: see this may be you will get some idea:http://thewebstorebyg.wordpress.com/2013/01/11/custom-directions-panel-with-google-maps-api-v3/

Comment: Thanks, but it does not like my idea

Comment: And your question is... ?